# python class instance invoke get() without declaration

Tags: python

I am reading mmdetecton project on github, and I'm so confused with code(I screened out all other irrelevant factors.):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self._dict_test = {"b": a}

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print("You call __getattr__ !")
        return getattr(self._dict_test, item)

test = A(2)
judge = test.get("b", False)
print("a is", test.a)
print("judge is ", judge)
print(test.__dict__)
```

I didn't declare the get() function in the class, I checked the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html) where it says:

> Attribute references are translated to lookups in this dictionary, e.g., m.x is equivalent to m.**dict**["x"].

So, 
（1）I wonder how should my code be interpreted? is it `test.__dict__.get()`, or `test.__dict__['get()']`
Has this ever happened to anyone?
（2）why **getattr** is invoked???
I check the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html) where it says

> **getattr** Called when the default attribute access fails with an AttributeError

but isn't get() the dict's function ? why get() fails with an AttributeError?
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use, and thanks in advance!

Comment: `test.get` is an attribute access on `test`, and the default attribute access fails.

Comment: yeah, I get it, thank you very much~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `__getattr__` method, you will see an exception:

```
    judge = test.get("b", False)
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'get'
```

because there is no `get` defined in the `A` class.

With the `__getattr__` method, `test.get` evaluates to `getattr(self._dict_test, item)` inside that method which is `getattr(test._dict_test, "get")` which is `test._dict_test.get` which is the usual `dict.get` method for `test._dict_test`, not `test.__dict__`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I follow your instruction, Does __getattr__ take the whole `get("b", False) `as an argument, so, finally, `test._dict_test.get("b", False)`, Am I right?

Comment: @Meepo no, it just gets `item="get"` and returns the method object `test._dict_test.get`. So `test.get` evaluates to `test._dict_test.get`. From there things proceed as normal without involving `__getattr__` further.

Comment: I get it! Sincerely, thank you very much for your reply!